# why cannot print image in widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

In wordpress, widget function, when I only added these two sentences in widget function:

```
$file = "badge.png";
echo '<img src= "'. WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/ose-firewall/images/'.$file.'" border = "0" />';
```

It's able to show the image on the webpage, however, when I added the if...else, it doesn't work. Can someone help me with that?

```
public function widget($args, $instance){




            oseFirewall::callLibClass('vsscanner','vsscanner');
            $scanner = new vsscanner();
            $log = $scanner->getScanninglog();


            if (empty($log))
            {
                $file = "badge.png";
                echo '<img src= "'. WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/ose-firewall/images/'.$file.'" border = "0" />';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a text widget and move the widget to where you want it to display.

```
<img src="URL OF IMAGE" alt="TEXT WHEN HOVERING OVER IT">
```

You can add further code such as width and height to alter the size of it as well.

Comment: This is not an answer :/